# Spring-Boot with CustomAuthenticationProvider and CustomPasswordEncoder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Its not clear for me how to glue my CustomPasswordEncoder to the authentication process of spring boot. I define in a configuration that spring boot should use my CustomAuthenticationProvider with my UserDetailsService and my CustomPasswordEncoder

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;


    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {

        builder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new CustomPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }       
}
```

My CustomPasswordEncoder will encode to a md5 value (I know its unsecure, but its a legacy database)

```
@Component
public class CustomPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder{

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
return DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(rawPassword.toString().getBytes());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {

        return rawPassword.toString().equals(encodedPassword);
    }
}
```

In the CustomAuthtenticationProvider the authentication check will be done. The delivered password will be encoded by using the passwordEncoder.encode() The user will be fetched from the database, then I am using the passwordEncoder again do a match. If the match is successfull then the authentication object will be generated.

```
    @Component
    public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        @Autowired
        private UserServiceImpl userService;
        @Autowired
        private CustomPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;



        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            System.out.println("authentication = [" + authentication + "]");
            String name = authentication.getName();
            Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();

            String password = credentials.toString();
            //why is this necessary isnt it called automatically?
            String passwordEncoded = passwordEncoder.encode((CharSequence) credentials);
            Optional<UserEntity> userOptional = userService.findByUsername(name);

            if (userOptional.isPresent() && passwordEncoder.matches(passwordEncoded, userOptional.get().getPassword())) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userOptional.get().getRoles().toString()));
                Authentication auth = new
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuthorities);
                return auth;
            }
            else{
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed for " + name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
        }
    }
```

Is this the correct approach? I thought the CustomPasswordEncoder will be used "automatically" or ist that only the case if you use one of the provided authenticationProviders like jdbcAuthenticationProvider. Maybe someone can explain the order of events of the authentication process. I did some research in the net but still I cannot understand this in detail.

Comment: Why do you have a custom authentication provider? Also the encoding of the password should be in the `matches` method. As that will validate the `rawPassword` (as entered by the user) with the `encoded` password. So put it in the `matches` method instead of what you currently do. Instead of your custom `AuthenticationProvider` just create a `UserDetailsService` wrapper/adapter for your `UserServiceImpl` and inject that. Spring Security will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as you can see from the [`matches`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html#matches-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.String-) method it validates the raw password (thus as entered by the user) with the encoded password. So the code for encoding belongs in the `matches` method instead of what you have now.

```
public class CustomPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder{

    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
      return DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(rawPassword.toString().getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
        String rawEncoded = encode(rawPassword);
        return Objects.equals(rawEncoded, encodedPassword);
    }
}
```

Now you can remove the encoding line/step whatever from your code.

However you don't really need a custom `AuthenticationProvider` as that is generally only needed if you add another authentication mechanism like LDAP or OAuth.

What you need is an adapter for your `UserService` to a [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) and use that. I assume that the `UserDetailsServiceImpl` does exactly that. If not you can use something like the code below.

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService delegate;

    public UserDetailsServiceAdapter(UserService delegate) {
        this.delegate=delegate;
    }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
       reutrn userService.findByUsername(name)
                 .map(this::toUserDetails).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown user " + username);
    }

    private UserDetails toUserDetails(User user) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(r -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r));
         return new UserDetails(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

Now you can use your `PasswordEncoder` and this adapter in the configuration and you don't need your custom `AuthenticationProvider`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {

        builder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
               .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new CustomPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am going to try this. Can you explain what is happening under the hood? Which AuthenticationProvider will be used when I dont configure one?

Comment: You cannot have no authentication provider. You either have to configure one by adding a datasource and queries leading to a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` or by injecting a `UserDetailsService` leading to again the `DauAuthenticationProvider` or create a custom one. So you will always have an `AuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: In my case, I have two Datasources which one does it take? The primary one or the one which is "bound" to the Entity class which will be used by the UserDetails?

Comment: Depends on what you configred your `UserService` to use.